# Updating time in AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I want to display random notification within a day, so I have set an alarm which take what time to be trigger as a value through my Shared Preferences, the default value is 10.The code is the following:

```
    Calendar calendar;

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    int nextAlarm = prefs.getInt("nextAlarm", 10);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationBarAlarm.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, nextAlarm);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    long alarmmills = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmmills, pi);
```

The alarm is sending a pending intent to active my notification process. Whenever the notification is be called I calculate the current time milliseconds plus a random amount of milliseconds, I convert them into hours and I store the time in my Shared Preference so to use it for my next alarm. Finally I am send an Intent to my Alarm Service so to update it.The code is the following:

```
NotificationManager notifyManager;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Time time = new Time();
    long currenttimeMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    time.set(currenttimeMilliseconds);
    int t = time.hour;

    //Random time 

     Random rand=new Random();
    int min = 1, max = 2;
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    long randomMilli=randomNum *60*60*1000;

      long updatedTime= currenttimeMilliseconds + 10800000 +randomMilli;

        Time nextalarmmill = new Time();
        nextalarmmill.set(updatedTime);
        int nextalarm = nextalarmmill.hour;

    SharedPreferences prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("nextAlarm", nextalarm);
    editor.commit();


    if (t >= 10 && t <= 22) {           

        notifyManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "A new notification just popped in!",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notif.sound = alarmSound;
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Notification",
                "A new notification", contentIntent);
        notifyManager.notify(1, notif);

    }

     Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
     context.startService(serviceIntent);


}
```

It is working correctly untill the day change. For example on 27/07 when at  21:00 pm I call a notification the next alarm is setted to be activated(randomly after 4 or 5 hours) lets say at  01:00 am.   The alarm does not understand that 01:00 does not refer to the present day(27/07) but to the next one (28/7). As a result it trigers immediately my notification receiver which in turn activate again my alarm Service creating a loop.

How can I set my alarm so to understand when the day has been change ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding that:

```
if (nextAlarm < calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

after

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: I just tried it but unfortunately it still facing the same problem